# packetfence servies does not start right after installation

Tags: centos, captive-portal

I have installed packetfence on centos 7.2.

every goes smooth during installation but after successfully installation 
packetfence service is not starting .

I tried to start manually but it does not start .

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl status packetfence -l
● packetfence.service - PacketFence Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/packetfence.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2016-11-21 10:17:35 PKT; 1h 16min ago
  Process: 58132 ExecStop=/usr/local/pf/bin/pfcmd service pf stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 58053 ExecStart=/usr/local/pf/bin/pfcmd service pf start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: pfconfig                    | interact with pfconfig
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: portalprofileconfig         | query/modify portal profile configuration parameters
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: reload                      | rebuild fingerprint or violations tables without restart
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: service                     | start/stop/restart and get PF daemon status
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: schedule                    | Nessus scan scheduling
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: switchconfig                | query/modify switches.conf configuration parameters
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: version                     | output version information
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: violationconfig             | query/modify violations.conf configuration parameters
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[58132]: Please view "pfcmd help <command>" for details on each option
Nov 21 10:17:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PacketFence Service.
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# 

[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl  restart  packetfence
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# systemctl status packetfence -l
● packetfence.service - PacketFence Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/packetfence.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2016-11-21 11:34:41 PKT; 14s ago
  Process: 60279 ExecStop=/usr/local/pf/bin/pfcmd service pf stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 60195 ExecStart=/usr/local/pf/bin/pfcmd service pf start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: pfconfig                    | interact with pfconfig
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: portalprofileconfig         | query/modify portal profile configuration parameters
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: reload                      | rebuild fingerprint or violations tables without restart
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: service                     | start/stop/restart and get PF daemon status
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: schedule                    | Nessus scan scheduling
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: switchconfig                | query/modify switches.conf configuration parameters
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: version                     | output version information
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: violationconfig             | query/modify violations.conf configuration parameters
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain pfcmd[60279]: Please view "pfcmd help <command>" for details on each option
Nov 21 11:34:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started PacketFence Service.
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]#
```

Is there any guide which i follow step by step or pre build iso file which i can use on centos 7.2 (7) for testing